# find article text Regex Python

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I have wrote a simple python script to parse text file. But my regex need modification to find more than one line in second group.

```py
import re


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sonnik = open('sonnik.txt').read().decode('utf-8')
    article = re.compile(ur'^([A-Za-zА-Яа-я0-9_\-:,\.«» ]+)[\n]{2}^[ ]{5}([A-Za-zА-Яа-я0-9_\-:,\.«» ]+)$',re.M|re.U)
    result = article.findall(sonnik)
    print len(result)

    print '-----'
    print result[0][1].decode('utf-8')
    print '-----'
```

Example of source text file:

```
Банкет

     Видеть во сне банкет - хорошо. Друзья будут к Вам благосклонны. Видеть во сне себя в толпе веселых, нарядно одетых гостей, которые едят на дорогой посуде и пьют старые вина баснословной стоимости, предвещает огромную удачу в любых начинаниях и счастье в кругу друзей.
     Видеть недружелюбие среди гостей, нелепые пустые столы - является знаком очень тяжелых недоразумений, размолвок и разочарований, ожидающих Вас.

Банкрот

     Если Вам снится сон, в котором Вы не можете расплатиться с долгами и чувствуете себя банкротом - то в реальной жизни не бойтесь угрозы с этой стороны. Напротив, Ваша энергия и уверенность в себе позволяет Вам наилучшим образом организовать свои дела.
     Однако иные тревоги могут смутить Вашу душу.
     Если Вы видите банкротами других, то это означает, что наяву Вам встретятся люди благородные, честные в делах, хотя, возможно, излишней откровенностью они могут Вам навредить.
     Молодой особе этот сон обещает небольшую размолвку с любимым, виной чему разность их взглядов.
```

Term and article pair. Article text placed between new lines after term with 5 whitespace indent. Current regex match only first line from text. Is it possible change regex to use something like loop for group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could add:

```
(?:\n^[ ]{5}[A-Za-zА-Яа-я0-9_\-:,\.«» ]+)*
```

After the second capture group, as in:

```
^([A-Za-zА-Яа-я0-9_\-:,\.«» ]+)\n{2}^[ ]{5}([A-Za-zА-Яа-я0-9_\-:,\.«» ]+(?:\n^[ ]{5}[A-Za-zА-Яа-я0-9_\-:,\.«» ]+)*)$
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/iL6bM3)

Comment: Thanks, its works. As I understand this non-captured group match only last row of article and this extend diapason of group.

Comment: @Dimm It matches each other row following the first article row. The way it works is that it tries to find the 5 spaces indent and if there's no match, it stops there. That's how it can match the last row of the article :)